# JSON Error Occurred in registration

Tags: php, android, json

I'm following a tutorial on learn2crack. I've made a few changes and I keep getting an error. I've tried going through the code line by line(2 days now) but i can't find the problem. Data from the app is stored in mysql database by the way and the app keeps displaying the "Contacting servers" process dialogue(and doesn't stop). with all my tinkering i'm certain its a server-side problem. How can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Stacktrace

```
04-03 22:01:19.448: E/JSON(2575): {"tag":"register","success":0,"error":1,"error_msg":"JSON Error occured in Registration"}
```

part of the index.php

```
else if ($tag == 'register') {
    // Request type is Register new user
    $zica_number = $_POST['zica_number'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



    // check if user is already existed
                // store user
        $user = $db->storeUser($zica_number, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["first_name"];
        $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["last_name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["zica_number"] = $user["zica_number"];
        $response["user"]["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured in Registration";
            echo json_encode($response);

    }
} else {
     $response["error"] = 3;
     $response["error_msg"] = "JSON ERROR";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
    echo "Learn2Crack Login API";
}
```

part of dbfunctions.php

```
/**
     * Adding new user to mysql database
     * returns user details
     */

    public function storeUser( $first_name, $last_name, $email, $zica_number, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO student(unique_id, first_name, last_name, email,  zica_number, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$zica_number', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the line of code that's causing the problem?

Comment: the error message "JSON error occurred in registration" is what shows up in LogCat

Answer (score 0):

You seem to pass the parameters incorrectly for storeUser:

You pass:

```
 $user = $db->storeUser($zica_number, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $password);
```

but the method signature is:

```
storeUser( $first_name, $last_name, $email, $zica_number, $password)
```

try changing it to:

```
$user = $db->storeUser($first_name, $last_name, $email, $zica_number, $password);
```

Comment: I made the change. The result is still the same.

Comment: Okay, well print out the error then...I assume there is a SQL error being thrown. Do something like if(!$result) {     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }

Comment: you're also using deprecated mysql_ methods. You should use mysqli_ or PDO instead. Check out the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: in which file? dbfunctions.php?

Comment: as soon as i get this working i want to change to PDO

Answer (score 0):

I have been following the same tutorial and I am stuck in a related problem. I find that the problem is related with the DB_Functions.php that not execute the querys in the "storeUser" function. I succesfully print the INSERT statement but the register is not inserted. Manually execution of sql INSERT make the job.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users(unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, NIS, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$NIS', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"; 

echo $sql."\n";
```

Here I tried to put the global connection ($db) value with no success.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
```

The insert statement printed out:

```
INSERT INTO users(unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, NIS, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('551f918bec5ec5.00635370', 'Harvey', 'Jarquin', 'hjarquin@gmail.com', '8899', 'TYADKQoRgGUHdAV9/b1djRDZGXU0NzQ4NGIzN2Ez', '47484b37a3', NOW())
```

I tried a simple "select * from users;" with no success. Any help would very appreciated.

Thanks.

### EDITED

Finally I solved it.

First: Move all .php script to the same folder (index, config, DB_CONNECT, DB_FUNCTIONS)

Second: Edited the DB_FUNCTIONS variable "db" declaration that is overlapping the db variable declaration of the index.php

```
class DB_Functions {


private $dbcon;  //edited this change the name

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php'; //fix the include path
    // connecting to database
    $this->dbcon = new DB_Connect(); //edited this change the name "dbcon"
    $this->dbcon->connect(); //edited this change the name "dbcon"

}

// destructor
function __destruct() {

}
```